# Is synchronizing two methods separately equivalent to synchronizing the block in which these two methods are called?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Can I get your views on this.

"Given the scenario: This class is intended to allow users to write a series of messages, so that each message is identified with a timestamp and the name of the thread that wrote the message

```
public class Logger
{
    private StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();

    public void log(String message)
    {
        contents.append(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        contents.append("message");
        contents.append("\n");
    }

    public String getContents()
    {
        return contents.toString();
    }
}
```

How can we ensure that instances of this class can be safely used by multiple threads?"

Apparently, the right answer is "Synchronize both log() and getContents()".

In my opinion, this would still not be enough, as one thread could still be pulling out other thread's message, when it called the getContent() method. Am I wrong?

could it not happen that the thread looses the lock to another thread, between writing the message and eventually invoking the getContent()?

e.g. in UtilityClass

```
Logger logger = new Logger();
```

in MyThread..

```
// Get logger instance
Logger myLogger = utilityClass.getLogger();

// doSomething else, release lock on 'logger' instance
// other thread gets the Logger from utility class, and invokes the log() method on it

// MyThread now calls getContent(), getting the other thread's message
myLogger.getContent()
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: Define "safely". If you synchronize both methods, then: one log messages won't be added in the middle of another, `getContents` will never return half a log message (cut off at the end), and it won't crash because of concurrency problems.

Comment: Nobody said that any thread was not supposed to see the other thread's messages. Nor that it needs to hold the lock between writing the data and getting the content.

Comment: not exactly because in synchronize black case you are restricting user to call from synchronize block. but user might call those method with synchronization so better way is to make method synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed if only the methods are synchronized, only the method calls will be atomic. Do you really need the logger to be specific to a thread ? If so you may want to change your design to suit that need, using ThreadLocal for instance if you **really need** thread compartmentalization.

Comment: So synchronizing both methods will not make the class thread safe correct?

Comment: This is not relevant to the given assignment, which clearly collects messages from multiple threads, and is not intended to be a log for a single thread (otherwise, why would you tag the message with the thread identifier anyway?)

Comment: @user3678484: I think you are confusing what thread safety is.  Thread safety is not an all or none property of classes (a class may be conditionally or unconditionally thread safe, for example).  You need to determine a thread safety policy for your classes that makes sense in the context of your application.

Comment: @Pouriya:  ThreadLocal shouldn't be needed here.  His class contains no static fields.  If all his class instances are already thread confined, then his objects are already thread safe even though there are no ThreadLocal variables.

Comment: @scootb: I know but he's using static methods and fields and did mention  not wanting "one thread [...] pulling out other thread's message".

Answer (score 0):

With the code you have posted (unsynchronized) there is clearly a point (marked below) where if `getContents` is called it would receive an incomplete record. Clearly some synchronization must be added.

```
public class Logger {

    private StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();

    public void log(String message) {
        contents.append(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        // << getContents called at this point.
        contents.append(message);
        contents.append("\n");
    }

    public String getContents() {
        return contents.toString();
    }
}
```

The problem is now clear - you must ensure that while `log` is executing, no other thread can call `getContents` and therefore, obviously, **both** must be synchronized.

```
public class Logger {

    private StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();

    public synchronized void log(String message) {
        contents.append(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        // << getContents called at this point.
        contents.append(message);
        contents.append("\n");
    }

    public synchronized String getContents() {
        return contents.toString();
    }
}
```

That **should** guarantee that no partial log entry will ever be returned by `getContents`.

There are, however, still some holes where an inconsistency could creep in (e.g. one thread does not see a recent message posted by another) but none would cause obvious errors such as malformed log entries.

Clearly:

```
public void test() {
    Logger logger = new Logger();

    logger.log("Hello");
    String contents = logger.getContents();
    // Contents could easily contain "Hello" and more but this would not be consider an error.
}
```

could result in unexpected results such as more log entries after the *Hello* entry but that would not be an error.

BTW: You do not have an timestamping in your log method.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that `StringBuilder` is not thread safe. So you don't want multiple threads to call the methods.

However, when you use the `synchronized` keyword in a method's signature it does not only mean that 2 threads can't simultaneously access the specific method. **The keyword `synchronized` locks the entire object**, not just that specific method.

Assuming that both methods have the `synchronized` keyword, if one thread will access the `getContents`method no other thread will be able to access the `log` method at the same time.

PS: **Alternatively you could use a `StringBuffer` which is thread-safe**. So you wouldn't need any kind of locking at all.